# I am not able to ping the IPv6 address asigned to the interface on CentOS 5

Tags: centos5, ipv6, linux-networking

I have assigned a stativ IPv6 address to eth2 interface and I am not able to ping it.

Here is the configuration setup done in `/etc/sysconfig/networking/device/ifcfg-eh2`

```
# Intel Corporation 82546EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
DEVICE=eth2
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=00:11:0A:56:BB:68
ONBOOT=yes
HOTPLUG=no
DHCP_HOSTNAME=ipv6-http-ftp
TYPE=Ethernet
USERCTL=yes
IPV6INIT=yes
PEERDNS=no
IPV6ADDR=2001:dbc0:0a0a:0101:0000:0000:0000:0300
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=2001:dbc0:0a0a:0101:0000:0000:0000:0001
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
```

ifconfig eth2 does show link local address it shows only global address.

```
ifconfig eth2
eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:0A:56:BB:68
          inet6 addr: 2001:dbc0:a0a:101::300/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

output of ip -6 route show

```
ip -6 route show
unreachable ::/96 dev lo  metric 1024  expires 21333176sec error -101 mtu 16436 advmss 16376 hoplimit 4294967295
unreachable ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96 dev lo  metric 1024  expires 21333176sec error -101 mtu 16436 advmss 16376 hoplimit 4294967295
2001:dbc0:a0a:101::/64 dev eth2  metric 256  expires 21333176sec mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
unreachable 2002:a00::/24 dev lo  metric 1024  expires 21333176sec error -101 mtu 16436 advmss 16376 hoplimit 4294967295
unreachable 2002:7f00::/24 dev lo  metric 1024  expires 21333176sec error -101 mtu 16436 advmss 16376 hoplimit 4294967295
unreachable 2002:a9fe::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  expires 21333176sec error -101 mtu 16436 advmss 16376 hoplimit 4294967295
unreachable 2002:ac10::/28 dev lo  metric 1024  expires 21333176sec error -101 mtu 16436 advmss 16376 hoplimit 4294967295
unreachable 2002:c0a8::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  expires 21333176sec error -101 mtu 16436 advmss 16376 hoplimit 4294967295
unreachable 2002:e000::/19 dev lo  metric 1024  expires 21333176sec error -101 mtu 16436 advmss 16376 hoplimit 4294967295
unreachable 3ffe:ffff::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  expires 21333176sec error -101 mtu 16436 advmss 16376 hoplimit 4294967295
fe80::/64 dev eth1  metric 256  expires 21333174sec mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
fe80::/64 dev eth2  metric 256  expires 21333176sec mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
default via 2001:dbc0:a0a:101::1 dev eth2  metric 1  expires 21333176sec mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
```

output of route -A inet6

```
Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                                 Next Hop                                Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
getnameinfo failed
[UNKNOWN]/64                                *                                       U     256    1        0 eth2
getnameinfo failed
[UNKNOWN]/64                                *                                       U     256    0        0 eth1
getnameinfo failed
[UNKNOWN]/64                                *                                       U     256    0        0 eth2
getnameinfo failed
*/0                                         [UNKNOWN]                               UG    1      0        0 eth2
localhost6.localdomain6/128                 *                                       U     0      2        1 lo
getnameinfo failed
[UNKNOWN]/128                               *                                       U     0      0        1 lo
getnameinfo failed
[UNKNOWN]/8                                 *                                       U     256    0        0 eth1
getnameinfo failed
[UNKNOWN]/8                                 *                                       U     256    0        0 eth2
```

I will appreciate any help

Comment: What is the content of /etc/sysconfig/network?

Comment: please provide your `ip -6 neigh` - I suspect that it is failing to find the next-hop router within the transit /64 that you are using

Comment: The hostname isn't resolvable?  That looks a bit messed up.

Comment: Since you say you aren't able to ping the address, can you show the results of trying to ping it?  Are you trying to ping it from the same subnet?